# How stop an HTMLAudioElement while its playing with JS?

Tags: javascript, html, audio

An application is playing an audio clip with the HTMLAudioElement nested in some JavaScript like below,

```
var s = new Audio('/sounds/s.wav');
s.play();
```

HTMLAudioElement docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLAudioElement

The problem is that the clip needs to play every time a user takes an action. But if the previous audio clip is still playing then the next clip will not play (be delayed or skip completely).

So is there a way to cutoff an audio clip, mid way while it's playing?

Something like `s.stop()`?

---

**UPDATE**

Maybe this is still a duplicate question...

There are multiple audio clips for different actions so if implemented `sound.pause();` and `sound.currentTime = 0;` from referenced duplicate question, it might look something like this, which could be run before each clip.

```
function stopSounds() {
    sound1.pause();
    sound1.currentTime = 0;

    sound2.pause();
    sound2.currentTime = 0;

    sound3.pause();
    sound3.currentTime = 0;

    sound4.pause();
    sound4.currentTime = 0;

    sound5.pause();
    sound5.currentTime = 0;

    sound6.pause();
    sound6.currentTime = 0;

    sound7.pause();
    sound7.currentTime = 0;
}
```

Comment: Sorry can you mark as duplicate again - don't think I can do it on my side.

Answer (score 0):

The function you're searching for is `s.pause();`
If you want to go to the beginning of the file if it's started again, then you have to set `s.currentTime = 0;` (as I know it starts playing immediately then, at least in Chrome).

Answer (score 0):

**Just Call this Function:**

```
  var s = new Audio('/sounds/s.wav');
  s.play(); 
  s.pause();
```